Otel Collector, TailSampling and SpanName
I'm trying to use OTEL Collector to filter out Traces from being emitted to my store.
I am using otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest, with tail_sampling
I have an event which runs about 1200 per second, I want to remove 90% of successful traces where the name is for this specific event. I want to keep all traces for this name which are either error state themselves, or contain a span which is in an error state.
I do not want to alter the sampling of any other traces emitted by my application.
I want the simplest possible configuration to achieve this.
I have this otel-collector-config.yaml, but am having trouble to get it to:

Correctly filter on Span Name.
Correctly keep all other Spans.
Filter out 90% of Traces/Spans for my matching events:

processors:

  batch:
    send_batch_size: 10000
    timeout: 1s

  tail_sampling:
    decision_wait: 30s
    num_traces: 50000
    policies:
      [
        {
          name: downsample-event,
          type: and,
          and: {
            and_sub_policy:
             [
              {
                name: name_filter, type: ottl_condition,
                ottl_condition: { error_mode: ignore, span: [ "name == \"MyEvent\"" ] }
              },
              { name: is_ok, type: status_code, status_code: { status_codes: [OK] } },
              { name: prob, type: probabilistic, probabilistic: { sampling_percentage: 10 } }
             ]
           }
         },
         {
           name: capture-everthing-else,
           type: always_sample
         },
       ]

My intention with this tail_sampling configuration is as follows:

Spans matching the name 'MyEvent', with a Status Code of OK, should be sampled at 10%.
Every other span should be captured.

Current holes:

I cannot filter correctly on Name for some reason?
I am not sure that this will enable the full 'tree' of Spans, where a sub-span of MyEvent contains an error.

ChatGPT is giving me extremely unhelpful suggestions for this configuration, and so I've come to ask the experts.

It is not currently possible using the tools currently available in tail sampling in the Otel Collector in Dec 2024.
This is because, you cannot filter out a specific NAME of a SPAN in a Trace.
Why?
Because the match happens for ANY span in a Trace, ANY child span not named 'MyEvent' INSIDE the 'MyEvent' root level span/trace, WILL BE MATCHED. And this causes us to capture all traces again.

In your ottl_condition property, you are filtering on spans when it looks like you should be filtering on span events.
To quote the OpenTelemetry documentation:

A Span [represents] an operation with a start and an end.

A Span Event [represents] a meaningful, singular point in time.


So you could try replacing this:
ottl_condition: { error_mode: ignore, span: [ "name == \"MyEvent\"" ] }

with this:
ottl_condition: { error_mode: ignore, spanevent: [ "name == \"MyEvent\"" ] }

similarly to one of the examples here.

Good catch, but I think thats just an artifact of my poor example. The span name is indeed MyEvent, it's not an event, it is a Span. I didn't consider this when writing the question.
I think my main issue is, how can I filter the underlying spans, of errors. These want the whole tree to be sampled, whereas if there are no sub-spans with errors, we should probabilistic sample.

Thanks for clarifying. I'll try to have another look if I have time. Is there any way you could provide some ready-to-go code for a [mre]? It's tricky to help without, and too time-consuming (for me, at least) to put something together from scratch.
